Exchange Online Powershell Get SMPT Address of Identity
I'm rather new to Powershell, but I am trying to get the Primary SMTP Address of all Shared Mailboxes in the domain in order to extract the privileges that users (and all users in groups) have on said Mailbox:
$permissions = Get-ExoMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Get-ExoMailboxPermission | Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights

$uniqueGroups = @{}

$groups = $permissions.User | where {$_ -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"} | where {$_ -notlike "*@*"}
$owners = $permissions | where {$_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"} | where {$_.User -notlike "*@*"} | Select-Object Identity

foreach ($owner in $owners) {
    $smpt = Get-ExoMailbox -Identity $owner | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress
    echo $smpt
}

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    if (-not $uniqueGroups.ContainsKey($group)) {
        $uniqueGroups[$group] = $true
        echo $group
        $groupmembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $group
        echo $groupmembers
    }
}

echo "Number of unique groups: $($uniqueGroups.Count)"

However, the Get-ExoMailbox -Identity $owner | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress statement throws the Error that the Identity can't be found. When I execute the Get-ExoMailbox command directly in Powershell with any of the error-throwing Identities, it works without any problems. Any help would be very appreciated.

Using $smpt = Get-ExoMailbox -Identity $owner.Identity | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress works because the Select-Object statement before returns an Object instead of a String.
